# Laravel order by column with data in format "Aug 2021", "Feb 2021"

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am working with this weird database structures, changing database structures is not the option, but how could I fetch data by order this columns `ready_for_homes`. Some of the data that are in databases are:

`Aug 2021`
`Feb 2020`,
`August 2020`,
`Jan 2021`,
`November 2020`

basically either they contain `m Y` or `M Y`,

I have tried with `->orderByRaw("STR_TO_DATE(ready_for_homes,'%M %Y') ASC");` but not ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be that your text dates do not provide a day component.  Given that the day doesn't matter, we can arbitrarily assign each date to the first of the month:

```php
->orderByRaw("STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01 ', ready_for_homes), '%d %M %Y')");
```